# For и переменное число переменных

Tags: lua

Для работы с lua захватами из коммандной строки написал скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
msg = arg[1] or error('No matching pattern!', 2)
text = io.read('*a')
for str in string.gmatch(text, msg) do
    io.write(str, '\n')
end
```

Единственная проблема: как сделать, чтобы for записал *все* результаты захвата в строку/таблицу? Т. е. шаблон `()(%S+)()`  будет возвращать только позицию начала слова - 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
local msg = arg[1] or error('No matching pattern!', 2)
local text = io.read('*a')
local iterator = text:gmatch(msg)
repeat
   local array = {iterator()}
   if array[1] then
      print(table.concat(array, ', '))
   end
until not array[1]
```